# Calculating a weighted sum with matrices, as used in neural networks.

Tags: matrices, neural-networks

I have been working with neural networks for some time without employing matrices. So for example, if you have an array of $n$ inputs $X_i$ to a neuron, each feeding that neuron via a connection with weight $W_i$ and the neuron has a sigmoid activation function $\sigma$ then the activation of that neuron (ignoring bias) will be:

$$
\sigma( \sum_{i=1}^{i=n}(X_i W_i) )
$$

But it seems that many other people think and talk about neural networks in terms of matrix operations. Sadly I seemed to have missed matrices in my education and am not comfortable with them at all. I am trying to educate myself but I feel I am getting some things confused. In particular, I have seen people say that the aforementioned function describing the activation of a neuron can be expressed as:

$$
\sigma( W^T X )
$$

This confuses me because if both W and X are $n \times 1$ matrices then surely $(W^T X)$ is an $n \times n$ matrix... surely the $\sigma$ function wants to take a single scalar argument? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The product is 1-by-1, i.e. a scalar, since transpose of W is 1-by-n and X is n-by-1.

Comment: No matter how they happen to be written on paper, when doing calculations always think of vectors (1-dimensional matrices) as being vertical, not horizontal.

Comment: So I had my vertical and horizontal the wrong way round! OK, perfect. If you put that as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: In the ML community, it is far more common to see vectors written in column form instead of row form. Also, many authors overload function notation to allow their activation function (which is really defined by a scalar-to-scalar function) to be applied elementwise to vectors and matrices. In other words, if your input is $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and the weights are $W\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, then the output of this layer would be written $\sigma(Wx)$, which is a $m\times 1$ vector.